# How to efficiently get the partitions of a BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery

Is there a way of getting a list of the partitions in a BigQuery date-partitioned table? Right now the best way I have found of do this is using the `_PARTITIONTIME` meta-column, but this needs to scan all the rows in all the partitions. Is there an equivalent to a `show partitions` call or maybe something in the `bq` command-line tool?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To list partitions in a table, query the table's summary partition by using the partition decorator separator ($) followed by **PARTITIONS_SUMMARY**. For example, the following command retrieves the partition IDs for table1:

```
SELECT partition_id from [mydataset.table1$__PARTITIONS_SUMMARY__];
```